# 2D mask for a specific color

Tags: python, image, rgb, scikit-image

I solved a problem with a loop, but it is both slow and unpythonic. I'm looking for a mask solution. If I were interested in pixels with values for a specific channel, that would be simple:

```
img[img[:,:,0]==64] = [0,0,0]
```

to turn them all black. I want to change a specific color, e.g. `[192,0,128]`, so I need all three channels, something like `img[ img[:,:,0]==192 and img[:,:,1]==0 and img[:,:,2]==128]=[0,0,0]` but of course this is wrong. I also tried `np.all(img==[192,0,128])` but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 7):

You were almost there:

```
np.all(img == [192,0,128], axis=-1)
```

gives what you're looking for. You need to specify an axis to do the dimension reduction, which corresponds to the color channel axis here.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I just used `numpy.logical_and()` and it did the trick!